# Decrypting AES with Javascript CryptoJS after encrypting with PHP mcrypt

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, mcrypt, cryptojs

**Encrypting in PHP with mcrypt**

```
<?php
$string = 'Secret Message';
$key = 'd4b494e4502a62edd695a903a94c2701';
$iv = '02f30dffbb0d084755f438f7d8be4a7d';

$encrypted = base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $key,
        $string,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv
    )
);
//$encrypted results in 'nYoFAiyDARVSI09lH/IPdim5TvE51izVjk6sc2AK9Rg='
?>
```

**Decrypting in Javascript with CryptoJS**

```
<script>
var encrypted = 'nYoFAiyDARVSI09lH/IPdim5TvE51izVjk6sc2AK9Rg=';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('d4b494e4502a62edd695a903a94c2701');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('02f30dffbb0d084755f438f7d8be4a7d');

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,key,{iv:iv,mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); //prints an empty string
</script>
```

**I can't figure out how to get the Javascript side to spit out the original text.**

Comment: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is *not* AES; MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is.

Comment: Thanks, but then is there a way to decrypt RIJNDAEL cipher with 256-bit blocks in javascript?

Comment: Sure, find a Rijndael javascript implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Also, when I change the block size in php to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Did you mean MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in the previous comment? Anyway, the padding used by mcrypt_encrypt is incompatible with everything else, in particular the PKCS7 padding used by Javascript. See owlstead's [answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672012/mcrypt-encrypt-adding-s-bunch-of-00-to-end-of-string#23446527) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I meant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in my previous comment. Thanks, I'll look in to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLVED**

*Note: I found out that "MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256" in PHP's mcrypt is NOT included in AES. It uses the Rijndael method, BUT with a 256-bit block size (not included in AES). So, CryptoJS does not handle 256-bit block sizes for Rijndael. Thanks, GregS*

**Nonetheless**, I found an implementation that successfully decrypted the ciphertext I get from running my PHP mcrypt function above, using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 (Rijndael, 256-bit block size, with 256-bit key/32-byte key).

**Here it is:
https://code.google.com/p/js-mcrypt/**

```
<script>
var encrypted = 'nYoFAiyDARVSI09lH/IPdim5TvE51izVjk6sc2AK9Rg=';
var key = 'd4b494e4502a62edd695a903a94c2701';
var iv = '02f30dffbb0d084755f438f7d8be4a7d';
var decrypted = mcrypt.Decrypt(atob(encrypted), iv, key, 'rijndael-256', 'cbc');
</script>
```

I hope this helps someone as I spent a week of my spare time trying to figure this out and almost giving up.

Comment: It works well for me. but after decryption i am getting extra spaces. could you help me about that.

Comment: Just Use `decrypted.replace(/\0/g, 'your replacement text');`