# Encrypt in VB.NET Rijndael Managed and Decrypt in Javascript CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, vb.net, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm making an app that has to decrypt QRs and well... It doesn't, because i get the QR string but i cannot decrypt it.

I'm using this encryption method in VB.NET, and it works perfectly when i read an decrypt from VB.NET:

```
Private Function GetCodedQR(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim sToEncrypt As String = str

    Dim encrypted() As Byte
    ' Create an Rijndael object
    ' with the specified key and IV.
    Using rijAlg = Rijndael.Create()

        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        rijAlg.KeySize = 256
        rijAlg.BlockSize = 256
        rijAlg.Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678912345678912345678912345")
        rijAlg.IV = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("123452hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y")

        ' Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV)
        ' Create the streams used for encryption.
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)

                    'Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(sToEncrypt)
                End Using
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    sToEncrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)

    Return sToEncrypt
End Function
```

But when im using JS (CryptoJS) to decrypt the message it just dont work!

```
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('123452hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y');
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, '12345678912345678912345678912345', { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding });
```

Please help me I'm doing my best but JS is not my thing.

Comment: Solved i moved to mcrypt
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623768/decrypting-aes-with-javascript-cryptojs-after-encrypting-with-php-mcrypt